# entity framework grouping by datetime

Tags: linq, datetime, entity-framework-4

Every 5 minutes a row in a sql server table is added. The fields are:
DateTime timeMark,Int total.

Using entity framework I want to populate a new list covering a whole week of five minute values using an average of the totals from the last three months.

How would I accomplish this with Entity Framework?

Comment: question is not clear at my eyes ("whole week of five minute using an average of the totals from the last three months"), and you don't show any try... Could you please update your question ?

Comment: ok the log table is updated every 5 minutes. I want to be able to summarise (average) the last three months for every five minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your log is really exact on the "five mintues", and that I understood well
, you want a list with 7 day * 24 hours * (60/5) minutes, so 2016 results ?

```
//define a startDate
var beginningDate = <the date 3 month ago to start with>;

//get the endDate
var endDate = beginningDate.AddMonths(3);
var list = myTable.Where(m => m.TimeMark >= beginningDate && m.TimeMark <=endDate)
           //group by dayofWeek, hour and minute will give you data for each distinct day of week, hour and minutes
           .GroupBy(m => new {
               dayofWeek = SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", m.TimeMark),
               hour = SqlFunction.DatePart("hour", m.TimeMark),
               minute = SqlFunctions.DatePart("minute", m.TimeMark)
           })
           .Select(g => new {
               g.Key.dayofWeek, 
               g.Key.hour, 
               g.Key.minute,
               total = g.Average(x => x.Total)
           });
```

Comment: Yep as per your comments on TimeMark.DayOfWeek TimeMark.Hour etc  wont except those ectensions

Comment: @user2018978 but it works with SqlFunctions.DatePart version ?

Comment: I don't understand how you would use sql functions in linq ?

Comment: @user2018978 see msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466169.aspx and I edited the answer, you may try this new version (add `using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;` at the top of your file)

Comment: Thanks again! I wasn't aware of that class at all!

Comment: The last part of the Linq is not working though... .Select(g => new {
               g.dayOfWeek,

Comment: or use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.TimeMark)`